# Implementing state machine to read-write data in data flash

Tags: c, state-machine

I am trying to implement a state machine to read and write data to a 128K x 8 data flash.
I am planning to have the following states in the state machine:-

```
typedef enum DATA_FLASH_TASK_LIST
{
IDLE = 0;
INIT,
READ,
WRITE,
VERIFY
}
```

The state machine function will look like this:-

//dataflash.c file

//Global variable to keep track of data flash tasks

```
DATA_FLASH_TASK_LIST Current_DataFlash_Task = IDLE;

void DataFlashStateMachine()
{
switch(Current_DataFlash_Task)
{
case IDLE:
{
//Wait for other tasks
Current_DataFlash_Task = IDLE;
}
break;

case INIT:
{
//Erase and initialize the data flash
Current_DataFlash_Task = IDLE;
}
break;

case READ:
{
//Call a function to read contents of data flash
//Address and length of data will be updated in global variables
//Read_Data(data, address, length);
Current_DataFlash_Task = VERIFY;
}
break;

case WRITE:
{
//Call a function to write contents to data flash
//Write_Data(data, address, length);
Current_DataFlash_Task = VERIFY;
}
break;

case VERIFY:
{
//Call a function to compare and verify the read/write data
Current_DataFlash_Task = IDLE
}
break;
}


//Function to check current data flash task
DATA_FLASH_TASK_LIST GetCurrentTask()
{
return Current_DataFlash_Task;
}


//Function to set new data flash task
void SetCurrentTask(DATA_FLASH_TASK_LIST New_DataFlash_Task)
{
Current_DataFlash_Task = New_DataFlash_Task;
}
```

//main.c file

```
int address;
int length;
unsigned char *data;
int main()
{
.
.
.
.
.
while(1)
{
//Continously poll the data flash state machine
DataFlashStateMachine();
}
}
```

//handle_events.c file

```
void handle_events()
{
//Write data
ifGetCurrentTask() == IDLE)
address = 0x8000;
data_length = 500;
SetCurrentTask(WRITE);


//Read data
ifGetCurrentTask() == IDLE)
address = 0x8000;
data_length = 500;
SetCurrentTask(READ);
}
```

I need help with the following questions:

1. In hanlde_events(), how to know if the read and write operations are completed? Should i implement global flags which return SUCCESS/FAILURE from the DataFlashStateMachine() function? If yes, how do i handle these flags?
2. Is there a better way of handling these operations?

Comment: Each HW device has its own specifics. You need to carefully study the documentation of your device, and the documentation will dictate the state machine to use, how much you should wait for things, how you can make sure that things actually happened...

Comment: Are you writing a low level driver or library that directly accesses the Flash memory (through SPI for example) ? Or are you using an existing interface like a Flash Translation Layer, or an OS ? In the first case, I think there is something missing in your state machine: the erase step. You cannot write directly to Flash memory, you have first to erase (a page or a sector, with different timings and constraints) and then program

Comment: No, i am not writing the low level drivers. Those are already in place. There's no os. Yes, i am erasing the sector before writing to it. I have not mentioned the code in detail, because my focus is how to know that the read-write operations are completed. I need to know them in the hanlde_events() function.